# Parsing a string efficiently

Tags: r

So I've got a column in my data frame that is essentially one long characteristic string that is used to encode about variables for each record. It might look something like this:

```
string<-c('001034002025003996','001934002199004888')
```

But much longer.

The strings are structured so each 6 characters are paired together. So you can look at the string above like this:

001034 002025 003996
001934 002199 004888

The first three characters of these is a code corresponding to a certain variable and the next three correspond to the value of that variable. So the above can be broken down into three columns that look like this:

```
   var001   var002   var003   var004
1   034       025     996       NA
2   934       199      NA      888
```

I need a way to parse this string and return a data frame with the expanded columns.

I wrote a nested loop that looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(string)){
  text <- string[i]
  for(j in seq(1,505,6)){
    var <- substr(text,j, j+2)
    var.value <- substr(text, j+3, j+5)
    index <- (as.numeric(var))
    df[i, index] <- var.value 
  }
 }
```

where df is an empty data frame created to receive the data. This works, but is slow on larger amounts of data. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** This one-liner produces a character matrix (which can easily be converted to a data.frame if need be). No packages are used.

```
read.dcf(textConnection(gsub("(...)(...)", "\\1: \\2\n", string)))
```

giving:

```
     001   002   003   004  
[1,] "034" "025" "996" NA   
[2,] "934" "199" NA    "888"
```

**2)** This alternative produces the same matrix.  The `read.table` produces a long form data.frame and then `tapply` reshapes it to a wide matrix.

```
long <- read.table(text = gsub("(...)(...)", "\\1 \\2\n", string), 
  colClasses = "character", col.names = c("id", "var"))
tapply(long$var, list(gl(length(string), nchar(string[1])/6), long$id), c)
```